# Oxyplot: Define labels of Y-Axis in ColumnSeries

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, oxyplot

i have a small problem with Oxyplot. I try to create a ColumnSeries and want the Y-Axis to display (more) labels.

At the moment it is looking like this:

[image]

As you can see, the labels on the Y-Axis go from 1 to 5 and they aren't even aligned to the marks.

Here's my code so far:

```
MyModel = new PlotModel { Title = "BarSeries" };
MyModel.Axes.Add(new CategoryAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Left, Maximum = 20, Unit = "€"});
MyModel.Axes.Add(new CategoryAxis { ItemsSource = players, LabelField = "Name" });
MyModel.Series.Add(new ColumnSeries { ItemsSource = players, ValueField = "Winnings" });
```

I think it's just a little adjustment on the first Axis, can you guys help me?

Comment: You can add labels with AddRange method.

Comment: Add `IsTickCentered = true` to your vertical axis, so that the ticks will be drawn in the middle of each category which is what you want to achieve: